# Копирование диапазона с одного листа в другой лист

Tags: excel, vba, copy

Есть книга, в которой 10 листов. Нужно скопировать содержимое 8-го листа в 3-й лист.

Я пытался сделать это следующим способом:

```
Set CurrentWorkbook = ThisWorkbook
Set sheetTemp = CurrentWorkbook.Worksheets(8)

With Application: .ScreenUpdating = False: .DisplayAlerts = False: End With
With CurrentWorkbook
     sheetTemp.Copy CurrentWorkbook.Worksheets(3)
End With
With Application: .ScreenUpdating = True: .DisplayAlerts = True: End With
```

Все работает, но вместо записи в 3-й лист оно создает перед третьим листом новый лист. Как сделать так, чтобы при копировании не создавался новый лист и записывалось в существующий лист?

Comment: метод Copy у Sheets не копирует содержимое листа, а копирует сам лист в другое расположение. Для того, чтобы скопировать содержимое, вам надо выделить содержимое на одном листе и вставить в другой

Comment: @Sublihim дело в том что в листе более 50 колонок и все имеют свою собственную ширину, по этому я и копирую что бы сохранялись пропорции колонок

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Полное копирование столбцов (ширина, форматирование, значения, примечания...):

```
Sub CopyRange()
    Worksheets("Лист1").Columns("C:E").Copy
    Worksheets("Лист2").Columns("C:E").PasteSpecial
End Sub
```

или

```
Sub CopyRange()
    Worksheets("Лист1").Columns("C:E").Copy Worksheets("Лист2").Columns("C:E")
End Sub
```

Для копирования только нужного:

```
  Worksheets("Лист1").Range("C3:E50").Copy

  With Worksheets("Лист2").Range("C3")
      .PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths ' ширина столбца'
      .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues' значения'
      .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats' форматы'
      .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats ' формулы'
      ' .....'
  End With
```

После копирования очистить буфер:

```
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```